# avoiding code duplication for const-overload and RVO

Tags: c++, rvo

For the sake of avoiding code duplication when dealing with const-overload I wrote something like this:

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> _data;
public:
    const A lightCopy() const
    {
        A a;
        a._data = _data;
        return a;
    }

    A lightCopy()
    {
        using const_a_t = const A;
        const_a_t &const_me = *this;
        return const_me.lightCopy(); // const object here
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    auto b = a.lightCopy();
}
```

`const_cast` is used in non-const version because otherwise it would be a non-const function call in const-method that will probably modify the object and will get away with it unnoticed (because of `const_cast`). And const-casting from non-const to const shouldn't cause any problems.

And question here is: since I can't const_cast an object — **is it possible that because invoked `lightCopy()` returns const object and actual return type is not const — RVO won't be possible and an additional copy will be made?**

Comment: Why do you have a non-`const` version if its behavior is identical anyway? I realize that this doesn't answer your question. However, in contexts where it actually matters the implementations or results of the `const` and non-`const` versions tend to differ in some form, e.g., in return references or pointers with different `const` qualification. ... and returning an object by value and `const` qualifying it is somewhat besides the point: clearly the type is copyable/movable, i.e., the user can get hold of a non-`const` qualified object anyway.

Comment: Is the copy from the `const A` to `A` additional or not?

Comment: @DietmarKühl const-version is here because I want to allow having a constant light copy when the parent object is constant. And if only non-const version is available -- when the parent object is constant there is no way to get a light copy.

Comment: @nwp Yes, copying from `const A` to `A` is additional because if I would copy-paste code to non-const version there would be no such copying.

Comment: Yes, sure. It should just return an `A` value and you should remove the non-`const` version. There is, as far as I can tell, no benefit to be gained from returning `const` qualified objects but it is certainly harmful if objects are movable otherwise.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I understand your point, but there is a problem: it is a light copy. So, I need to show that when original object is constant -- only constant light copy could be obtained. Otherwise, constant parent object could be modified via non-const light copy.

Comment: It seems you _don't_ understand my point! ... because you can obtain a non-`const` qualifed object from a `const` qualified object by simply copying it: `A const a; A non_const = a.light_copy();` You can't enforce propagation of `const`ness upon copying.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Interesting. Could you explain me this moment, please? In your example const-version of `lightCopy` is called and it returns constant object, but on the left side the object is not constant. Why copy-constructor is not called here?

Comment: @AlexanderSergeev: With my original answer you are right: the copy constructor would be invoked. I now understand that this was your actual objective: doing a "light copy" would merely return a reference as long as copy elision is used which would be turned into an actual copy by way of the copy constructor when put into a non-`const` object. The use of a non-`const` qualified object would have needed to create a copy. So, it would be a sort of CoW (copy-on-write) approach which assumes that a non-`const` object is being written to. With the modified answer I don't think that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy elision of temporary objects is permitted if the source and the destination have the same "cv-**un**qualified type" according to 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 31 third item in the list:

> when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move

That is, the quoted code copy elision *is* allowed.

Instrumenting the destructor in the original example shows that [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), [Intel's compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers), and [EDG's frontend](https://www.edg.com/index.php?location=c_frontend) elide the copies while [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/) does not. That is, there are only two destructor calls implying that all possibly elidable copies are elided. The copies are elided independent of how `b` is declared. I have declared `b` using `auto`, `A`, and `A const`.